# Modificar estilo de una clase de Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, vue.js

He copiado la siguiente plantilla de Bootstrap para usarlo en mi proyecto con Vue:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    Bootstrap
  </a>
</nav>
```

Me gustaría cambiar elementos de estilo de esta clase, como por ejemplo el `background-color` pero no se como.

He intentado crear un `id` para el `nav` y crear un estilo personalizado usando el `scoped`, pero no afecta en nada a la barra:

```
.navbar-light{
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Alguna idea de como hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes eliminar la clase bg-light y crear una con el background-color que quieras.

```css
.navcolor{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Color Nav</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Color Nav</h1>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navcolor">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Navbar</span>
        </div>
    </nav>

    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Vicent! Justo lo que necesitaba.